# The range of a continuous even function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, even-and-odd-functions

Is there any rule that says that this range cannot be $\mathbb{R}$? Apparently there is, but then what about functions like $\log |x|$?

Comment: Your function is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Isn't 0 not in the domain at $x=0$?

Comment: "Apparently there is": can you substantiate this claim ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = x\sin x$. It is easy to check that $f$ is even.

Also, $f$ is continuous and obtains arbitrarily large positive and negative values. You can use the intermediate value theorem to show that every real number is in the range of $f$.

Hence, $f$ is a continuous even function whose range is $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, there is no rule that a continuous even function cannot have all of $\mathbb{R}$ as its range.

Comment: So there's no such rule, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: $x \sin x $ is not a continuous function, hence it remains that OP stated rule is correct.